# coordinate detection via mobile phone

Tags: java, geolocation, gps, coordinates

I am curious how hard it would it be to detect current coordinates by mobile phone? I am planning to write a mobile application which will focus on phones that can run java (ie Samsung Omina) and it will be based on the location of the user so I can do some Google map action using the coords.

- Using GPS sounds like an idea, however I have very thin knowledge about it, for instance how tough would it be to write a java app that detects the location via GPS and would it require the permission of the operator?
- Are there any options if GPS is not a good way to achieve it ?IE I see at other topics a method named CellID but I don't know how it works.
- A good way to solve it via java?

Answer (score 1):

If you are stuck with Java I would look into Android. It is probably the only "viable" mobile OS out there where Java is the main supported language. With the new wave of Android phones I believe GPS is also becoming more expected (If it isn't already).

As far as familiarizing yourself with GPS and how it works with google maps with android:
[Android Location API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/index.html)